# how to change the selected value in materializecss select using jquery

Tags: jquery, materialize

I am using materializecss select, [docs](https://materializecss.com/select.html) here. But I cant change the selected value using jquery, I already tried:

```
    $("li_tag_here").attr("class","selected");
    $("li_tag_here").prop("class","selected");
```

But all not working!

Btw, I am using the li tags since materializecss creates ul tags in select tags, and i also tried using the select but also cant do it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone comes across this and encounter same problem. You can have the selectedIndex attribute of the select option.

```
$('select_tag_here').prop('selectedIndex',your_preferable_index);
```

and re-initialize the select option

```
$('select_tag_here').material_select();
```

Cheers!